# Store a large number as separate digits in an array

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I have a number which is 5000 digits long. I want to store it in an array like `int num[5000]` as separated digits. Like `num[0]` will contain the first digit, `num[12]` the 13th and so on. And of course I am not going to add that many commas. So, what can I do?

Comment: are you going to enter those number one by one and pressing enter?

Comment: No, like  ```char[10] = "abcdefghi"``` automatically stores the characters in respective indices, is there a workaround for integers?

Comment: so so you will pass string ? and we have to store in int array every digit?

Comment: You'll want to look at how the various available "bigint" libraries are implemented.

Comment: Well how about doing it exactly like that `char num[] = "5000123456789123456789...";` ? You are not going to need the full range of an `int` for single digits anyway. Then convert it with `-'0'` when using it.